# What are the dots on Danichirou's forehead?

Tags: sankarea

In the **Sankarea** manga and anime, Rea's father, Danichirou has a row of dots on his forehead:

[image][image]

What are these dots for and why are they there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe those are called bindi. They signify the third eye or the chakra of wisdom.

According to wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bindi_%28decoration%29, people wear it as a fashion statement nowadays...

Comment: I haven't seen such bindi in real life, though... Usually, it is a single dot.

Comment: @nhahtdh true, it *is* usually a single dot, but if you just do a google image search on bindi, you'll find that there are a lot of variations. Like I said, rather than some kind of religious or spiritual reason, many people have the bindi as a fashion statement or fad.